# Getting DnsPrefetchingEnabled issue on protractor while it works fine via Java

Tags: protractor

> Chrome version: 57.0.2987.110 Chrome web driver: 2.28 Protractor:
>   5.1.2 Node: 6.9.1

When I run my scripts via protractor I see this error:

> ERROR:configuration_policy_handler_list.cc(92)] Unknown policy:
>   DnsPrefetchingEnabled ERROR:configuration_policy_handler_list.cc(92)]
>   Unknown policy: PasswordManagerAllowShowPasswords

When I run the similar test case via Java selenium it works fine & does not return error like above.
So I am assuming local group policy is not an issue here but protractor is dealing with web driver in a different way than Java.

I have tried these Chrome options:

```
'chromeOptions': { 
  'args': ['incognito','--no-sandbox','--disable-gpu',
           '--disable-web-security','--DNS-prefetch-disable']
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
'chromeOptions': {'args': ['lang=en-GB',  'enable-precise-memory-info' , 'js-flags=--expose-gc', 'no-sandbox']}
```

I'm using this and works perfect for me.